# How to access parents' members from a inner class in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm trying to do scheduled operation let's say to check for user's credit left via web service call and update the user interface.

i've tried with quartz.net to implement the scheduling bit.i created an inner class in  the window class i need to update.That inner class has the method that calls the webservice and the result needs to be displayed back to the UI. 
here is an example of what i did.

```
 public partial class Window2 : Window
 {
    private int i;
    public Window2()
    {   
      InitializeComponent();
    }



    public class Myclass :IJob
    {
      public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
      {
       string result = doMyOperation();
       //i'll like to call parent label member of name lblNotif
       //is something like parent.lblNotif.Content = result;
       //possible?
      }

      public string doMyOperation()
      {
        //calling the wermethod to retreive user's balance
       return result = service.GetUsersBalace(user);
      }

    }
}
```

Well the quartz bit is working and this post is not about quartz. here are my questions

**Question 1** : How is it possible to access Window2 controls, for instace lable lblNotif?
**Question 2** : If my thinking about this is wrong, what is done as best practice to solve my kind of problem, where an application need to do an operation let's say every 5mn and update the the UI.
**Question 3** : i at first tried to use the backgroundworker and i felt like i can't do the scheduling bit with it.Is that correct or i'm wrong.

thanks for those who commented already and sorry for those who didn't get the meaning of my post.I hope this will be a bit clearer.Thanks for reading

Comment: I'm going to step out on a limb and say maybe from the following:

[1] Is your question about threading ? or using Quartz ? or why you are getting an exception ? or all three ?
[2] You seem to be looking for code that does things for you...Updating multiple windows from a thread does not require Quartz.
[3] What does "but i'm stacked at here" mean, exactly ?...a little lingo is cool, but people still need to understand you.
[4] Your question(s) are not really about the art or detail of trying to write code, needing help with basic exceptions is not going to fly.

No offense just observation.

Comment: @Rusty: [3] I guess he meant "stuck". I also get more the "foreign" vibe rather than "illiterate".

Comment: @Amadan Good point...although "but it does the operation once ain't it ?" has got me wildly confused on what that foreign vibe could be...interesting. Regardless, apologies all around for any offense.

Comment: @Rusty no problem, and i appreciate your correction.English is not my first language though.i'm here to learn so, advices and remarks are welcome.
And NO it doesn't do the operation once, i've written periodically,for example every 5mn thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this purpose convenient class BackgroundWorker. For more info see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply .i've seen backgroundworker too, but it does the operation once ain't it?What i need is a scheduler.unless i don't know the scheduler feature of Backgroudworker..

Answer (score 0):

To do an operation periodically on a separate thread, use System.Timers.Timer.  Its Elapsed event always runs on a new thread.